# Git ignore changes without removing file from repository

Tags: git, hook, ignore

We have a few config files in our repository, that need to be configured in a certain way locally to be able to start the application. However, these configurations are not supposed to be pushed into the remote repository. Furthermore, when switching branches, cherry picking etc. these changes should always persist.

An obvious way to achieve this would be to add the files to the .gitignore and remove them from the repository, but we need to have them in the repository - just without our local changes.

This is somewhat possible without any further doing, by stashing and unstashing the changes frequently (e.g. when cherry picking), but that's fairly annoying.

For example: We have a C# project with an `app.config`, in which we have placeholders for the properties (e.g. `$SECURITY_PROTOCOL_TYPE$`) that is replaced upon installation. However, for testing etc. we don't *install* the application, we just start it - but therefore (locally) `$SECURITY_PROTOCOL_TYPE$` has to be replaced with `TLS12`. When we cherry pick however, these local changes need to be stashed and unstashed, which is annoying. Furthermore, sometimes it happens that someone accidently commits & pushes those config files, which is just as annoying to fix.

The problem gets even more complicated, because sometimes we *do* need to make changes to those config files that need to be checked in - without our local configurations of course.

The only idea I have for solving this situation is to somehow use a hook that replaces the configs with the placeholders upon `commit` (and the other way round upon `merge`), but that'd be kind of awkward too.

Is there an elegant way of solving this with git?
Just to avoid misunderstandings: I don't want to know that the way our repository is set up is bad or anything like that, I just want a solution to this problem: I somehow need to *lock* files for git, so that git pretends they didn't change, unless I explicitly say so.

Comment: To instruct git to ignore changes in a tracked file, try `git update-index --assume-unchanged $path`, and `--no-assume-unchanged` to cancel the effect. To avoid stash/unstash for cherrypick, merge or rebase, there could be some methods to manipulate the index without touching the files in the working tree. To avoid committing sensitive content, try the clean filter, https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter. You can use `sed` or write your own script, in which it  reads contents from stdin and writes updated contents to stdout.

Comment: All Git solutions to this setup are inelegant. You already know that Git doesn't "like" this kind of setup, so no point mentioning that again. :-) The least-inelegant of the inelegant solutions is the skip-worktree method in Kaus Untwale's answer. Note that you can use either skip-worktree or assume-unchanged, but each has a different *intended* purpose in Git, and this isn't either of those.

Answer (score 6):

I run into this all the time. I achieved this by adding three shortcuts to my global git config.

```
alias.ignore=update-index --skip-worktree
alias.unignore=update-index --no-skip-worktree
alias.ignored=!git ls-files -v | grep "^S"
```

Now when I want to ignore a file I just run:

```
$git ignore <file-path>
```

Conversely if I want to include it:

```
$git unignore <file-path>
```

Third command just lists the currently ignored files

```
$git ignored
```

Comment: No I sometimes get the message `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:` for some of the ignored files when trying to switch branches.

Comment: @MetaColon This happens when you try to switch to a base branch that does not have the ignored changes from a temporary branch which has the ignored files. To resolve this, first unignore the files then run `git stash` then switch your branch. Now you can run `git stash apply` to bring the changes back and ignore the files again. Going forward, from this base branch, any new branch you create will carry over the ignore changes with it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks! Here is the 1liner to add these to a gitconfig: `git config --global alias.ignore 'update-index --skip-worktree' && git config --global alias.unignore 'update-index --no-skip-worktree' && git config --global alias.ignored '!git ls-files -v | grep "^S"'`